# Error while resetting MySQL Password

Tags: mysql

I was trying to retrieve my lost password as given in [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-windows-excerpt/5.0/en/resetting-permissions-windows.html). However I keep on getting the following error.

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqladmin --defaults-file="C:\\Prog
ram Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my-default.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.t
xt --console
mysqladmin: unknown variable 'init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt'
```

I tried with both `mysqladmin.exe` and `mysqld.exe` since as given in the example I don't have a `mysqld-nt.exe`.

The file my-default.ini exists.

**UPDATE**

The following I get after using the command with MySQLD,

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin>mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\Program
Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my-default.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt --
console
```

I get following output

as given,

```
2014-08-20 16:08:06 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is depreca
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentati
on for more details).
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool p
ages
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlo
cked functions
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] InnoDB: .\ibdata1 can't be opened in read-write
 mode
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] InnoDB: The system tablespace must be writable!

2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGIN
E failed.
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [ERROR] Aborting

2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Binlog end
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD
'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET
'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2014-08-20 16:08:06 8488 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

After this I start mysql service, I get Error.

---

### Services

Windows could not start the MySQL55 service on Local Computer.

Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly.

---

### OK

Comment: `C:\\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\
my-default.ini` is not the same as `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\
my-default.ini`. (`C:\\ `)

Comment: @TBA Which link are you talking about?

Comment: Srry, I updated, Infact I am getting this error mysqladmin: unknown variable 'init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt'

Comment: @TBA You're missing your quotes.

Comment: Oops sorry I was following that link ... Let me see...

Comment: Even after using c:/ I get this error mysqladmin: unknown variable 'init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt'

Comment: Please find updated question: